# Feedback loop for data stream in SPSS-Modeler

Tags: python, spss-modeler

I'm new to SPSS modeler, and I'm trying to implement a feedback loop in SPSS modeler with Python scripting. Currently my stream looks something like:

```
Data_import -> Derive_stats -> Conditional_Filter -> Output
```

What I need is to feed the output from the conditional filter back into the Derive_stats node, and run this loop until a condition is met on the stats, something like:

```
Data_import -> Derive_stats -> Conditional_Filter -> Output
                    ^                    |
                    |____________________|
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Perhaps this can be done even without python?

Thanks!
Pablo

Answer (score 0):

If you right click a node, you can choose "looping/conditional execution".

I have not personally used this feature but I am not sure of how else you would do this.